# How to select auto-complete text box items using arrow keys in c#

Tags: c#, keydown, autocompletebox

This is my code for setting source for auto-complete text box it works perfectly. 
But I want to know how to select the items using arrow keys.
Please help me..

```
public void GetSource()
        {
            List<string> listnew= prolg.GetSource();
            var listn = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
            listn.AddRange(listnew.ToArray());
            txt_category.AutoCompleteCustomSource = listn;
        }
```

Comment: Are you using any 3rd party control? what type of application is this?

Comment: i'm using visual studio I got the list to "listnew" variable using method another with same name. Problem is i cannot change items using arrow keys in the textbox

Comment: okey I made it sir :)
I just have to put this in FormLoad event (Y)